# Alternate Access Mapping - Internet

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, alternate-access-mapping

I want my SharePoint Web Application to be accessible publicly on the internet. I have added the public against the Internet Zone in Alternate Access Mapping and added a binding in IIS for this public URL. The site is still not accessible. Is there any further configuration required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make SharePoint available from the internet you need to ensure that it can be resolved via public-DNS first. This DNS record should point to a Network load balancer. That NLB should then expose SharePoint web applications (Port 80 and 443)

The AAM are just there to ensure SharePoint itself knows how to handle the different URLs correctly.

Comment: I tried pinging the URL from Command Prompt. It is giving request Timeout error.

Comment: Are you working in a corporate setting (Company) ? If so you need to get the networking guys involved usually. single server or farm? Do you have load balancing set up? private setup? Maybe expose the server directly then if it is a dev box... Like I said its not only adding an AAM... SP Needs to be reachable there also